# Can a Event Service be coupled to a route

Tags: 8, routes, symfony-services

I have created a custom service and have hooked into the "event_subscriber"  via tags in my custom service.yml

```
  demo_api.exception_handler_subscriber:
      class: Drupal\demo_api\Response\Handler
      tags:
          - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

With in this custom service I'm listening into KernelEvents::RESPONSE

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    // For this example I am using KernelEvents constants (see below a full list).
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['onResponse'];
    return $events;
}
```

The problem is I have some API request and I'm modifying the response for these request and returning a modified json format.

```
public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $apiFormatter = new ApiFormatter();
    $response->setContent(
        json_encode(
            $apiFormatter
            ->wrapResult(
                json_decode(
                    $response->getContent()
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

This is causing any web pages to respond as json.

I would like to limit this service to these API calls only and not be called on each request.

Any advice would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to restrict the event subscriber to a route then check for the route name:

```
public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {

  $route_name = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
  if ($route_name !== 'my.route.name') {
    return;
  }

  ...

}
```

Although in Drupal it might be best practice to get the route name from the `current_route_match` service:

```
$route_name = $this->routeMatch->getRouteName();
```

which you then need to inject in the event subscriber.